# Chrome Dev Tools : Code Folding

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to enable cold folding in the CodeMirror used in the sources panel of Chrome Dev Tools.

Normally you would enable this through an option

```
foldGutter: true
```

I can see that the options for CodeMirror are being handled via source_frame_module.js.
Is it possible to customize this file?

Comment: If the file is on your server, of course you can customize it. What's the problem?

Comment: You can create a chrome extension and inject the [folding](https://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldcode.js) codemirror extension. Note that CodeMirror is not loaded until you go to the sources tab, so injecting the folding file won't work until after that happens. After you get it injected, use `CodeMirror.defineInitHook` to set the option.

Comment: Chrome extensions dont yet have the availability to configure the CM instance in devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot modify anything about how CodeMirror in DevTools operates. The only thing that can be done is re-styling via a custom theme extension. There have been numerous bug reports asking for this kind of functionality, but due to security reasons it hasn't been acted on yet nor is planned to be as far as I know.